# Is Power Off Retract count relevant for SSD

Tags: ssd, smart

Is Power-ff retract count relevant for SSDs? I have tested my SSD under various scenarios, hard power removal and kernel panic, but the attribute value does not change. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the maufacturers reused this field to count "unsafe shutdowns" which occurs when the disk loose power supply suddently and have to use it's builtin battery to terminate its operations. It is surprising that a hard power removal does not make it grow... probably a vendor-dependent behavior.